# Spring: How to load my bean as the first bean when server startsup

Tags: java, spring, server, javabeans

I have a java application based upon spring and I have a bean that runs some connection test logic during server startup. If the connection test fails, I stop the server.

I need this bean as the first one to be loaded before any other beans performs some operations using the connection string.

Can someone help me figure out how I can load this connection test bean as the first bean please.

Ways tried:

- Bean lifecycle hooks such as InitializingBean, init-method, @PostConstruct won't work as they will get invoked for my specific bean but can't control what beans gets loaded before my desired bean.

Update:

- depends-on or @DependsOn worked.

Thanks

Comment: If you want your application to execute some operation as soon as it starts you may find the @PostConstruct annotation helpful?

Comment: Depending on the version of Spring you are using you may be able to use the @DependsOn annotation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/DependsOn.html)

Comment: @bonobo '@PostConstruct' does not work in this case as it is based upon the life cycle of a specific bean. If any other bean gets loaded before my desired bean, this won't help.

Comment: @j_b Tried using 'depends-on', but it didn't work for me. That is why I am looking for a way that would make my bean load as the first bean ever.

Comment: try annotation @Priority

Comment: What about @lazy connection bean @lazy(false) rest of beans lazy

Comment: @Nidhi257 I assume you mean '@Order' annotation. I couldn't find '@Priority' in any of the spring packages apart from in javax.annotations. But '@Order' is specific for spring boot. Does not work

Comment: @sjy Tried 'lazy-init' in the xml config. Does not work. The only way i am able to make it work is to introduce false dependency by injecting my bean into other beans.

Comment: `@DependsOn` is the way to go. All the beans using an connection should use `@DepensON("connection-check-bean")`. If it didn't work you didn't do it properly.

Comment: @M.Deinum My bad. depends-on worked for me, it just that because of some other errors I didn't notice it. Thanks